# Can we merge [rails-i18n] and [i18n-gem]?

Tags: discussion, retag-request

Both [rails-i18n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rails-i18n) and [i18n-gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/i18n-gem) refers same rubygem: https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n

I think they can be merged (or made synonym), but I don't know which tag should be a master.